# JTextArea does not scroll to the bottom after a highlight

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextarea

When i add JTextArea to a scrollpane..

I can add messages to the textArea
eg
JTextArea.append("\n" +message);

and it will scroll to the bottom of the JTextARea

BUT!

after i highlight the text area and add a mesage again it will not scroll to the bottom automatically.

Is this java problem, or something i should implement manually. because if it is not doing after just a highlight, than it is pretty dam weird.

Comment: @meagar, what is the point of deleting the only answer to the question?  Who cares if it is a link only answer. Even if it does go bad the worst thing that happens is that the OP continues to search. In the meantime the link will continue to provide a solution to anybody who happens on the this question. Deleting the answer because something might happen in the future seems counter productive